# Can someone give an example on how a promise in Node.js is better than using a callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback, promise

According to IBM, promises are a compelling alternative to callbacks.

Apart from the syntax difference, how does a promise differ from a callback function and what are the benefits of using a promise?

Comment: better composition, unified er handling, settle only ONCE, late-bind etc..

Comment: Would you mind linking your source at IBM? Surely they have given some reasons.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302455/is-there-really-a-fundamental-difference-between-callbacks-and-promises